# assigning local variables to the collection of a dataset in c#

Tags: c#, .net

Having trouble with something simple, because i've never done it before and couldnt find the exact solution. I've got a dataset populated by a stored proc. I just want to loop through it and assign some local variables to the output.

Here is the simplistic loop I am using:

```
  foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have a specific set of variables that I want to populate via the data in the ItemArray. Just need help with the syntax.

Pseudocoded:

```
      string a;
        string b;
        string c;

  foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
                    {
a = item 1 in this row
b = item 2 in this row
c = item 3 in this row
                    }
                }
            }
```

The a,b, and c assignments are what I need the syntax for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something tells me there's much much more wrong going on here, but FYI a `DataRow` has [an indexer property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwfe1t7z(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
object a;
object b;
object c;

foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        a = row[0];
        b = row[1];
        c = row[2];
//snip
```

Comment: so a = row[0]; will assign whatever item is in that data cell in that row at that indexed position to local var a?

Comment: @optionsix  A DataTable is a collection of rows, a row is a collection of columns, and a column has a value.  DataTables and DataRows have indexer properties, so to get the third row's fourth column value you could index into it thusly: table[2][3] (remember, zero index).

Comment: Got it. Figured it would be a simple answer, not sure why I was having so much trouble googling a specific answer to it. This works.

Comment: @optionsix always check the types of the objects you are dealing with.  Their interfaces will often let you know how to use them.  The quickwatch window is also pretty useful during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string a;
string b;
string c;

foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        var arr = row.ItemArray;
        if (arr.Length > 2){
            a = (string)arr[0];
            b = (string)arr[1];
            c = (string)arr[2];
        }
    }
}
```